# Push to state array React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add a task object in my tasks array by the addTask method, this method its getting the previous state and adding the new task, it works with `JSX` but not when I am using TypeScript. The error that I'm getting is

```
Type 'ITask[] | undefined' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.  TS2569
```

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

interface ITask {
    name: string;
    done: boolean;
}

interface IProps {

}

interface IState {
    newTask?: string;
    tasks?: Array<ITask>;
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState>{
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            newTask: '',
            tasks: []
        }
    }


    addTask(name:string) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            tasks: [...prevState.tasks, {name, done: false}]
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to explicitly type the new object as `ITask`, to tell the TypeScript compiler that you are pushing an object of type `ITask` to the `tasks` state.

In addition, `tasks` is optional. One way to get around this would be to  set a default value (empty array `[]`) when you are spreading it.

```
addTask(name:string) {
  const newTask: ITask = {name, done: false}
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    tasks: [...(prevState.tasks ?? []), newTask]
  }));
}
```

Given that `tasks` (and even `newTask`) is actually assigned a value on the constructor, there is actually no need to mark it as optional on your `IState` interface.

```
interface IState {
  newTask: string;
  tasks: Array<ITask>;
}
```

This will save you the need from checking if `tasks` is `undefined` when you are setting state.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast type of `{name, done: false}` to ITask before adding it to the array:

```
tasks: [...(prevState.tasks ?? []), {name: name, done: false} as ITask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to declare both fields correctly inside the object to pass.

```
// use: {name: name, done: false}
addTask(name:string) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        tasks: [...prevState.tasks, {name: name, done: false}]
    }));
}
```